# How to return const reference from std::optional::value_or?

Tags: c++

```
struct A
{
    static const bool mDefault = true;
    std::optional<bool> mValue;
    const bool& GetDefaultValue() { return mDefault; }
    const bool& GetValue() { return mValue.value_or( GetDefaultValue() ); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << A().GetValue() << std::endl;
}
```

When compile that code we obtain a `returning reference to temporary` warning cause `value_or` return by value.
There is a way to return a const reference?

Comment: My question would be why you need to return a `const&` to a type that is the cheapest possible to copy. Why not just return a value?

Comment: @underscore_d: Question is done with bool but we can imagine a generic type.

Answer (score 3):

`value_or` returns by value. It's already a copy. You'll have to do it yourself.

```
const bool& GetValue() { return mValue ? mValue.value() : mDefault; }
```

Comment: It is not a kind of repeat yourself?

Comment: @IsaacPascual if you need a `const &`, then no, it isn't repeating the definition of `value_or`

Comment: Im not agree... I think that standard must adress reference case with other `value_or` declaration

Comment: `value_or` retuns by value because that is safer and more general. It would be quite easy to have a dangling reference using a reference-returning `value_or`

Comment: The point is that if you pass a correct reference by argument there is no possible dangling reference

Comment: @IsaacPascual I'll give an example of what would be unsafe: `std::optional<int> opt; auto & ref = opt.value_or(1); std::cout << ref`. If `value_or` returned by reference, `ref` would dangle